# How to show $classname only once

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to echo $classname only once.
So it shows like this for example.

Puppy Dog

1st blah blah

2nd whoever

3rd extra

at present it shows like:

Puppy Dog

1st blah blah

Puppy Dog

2nd whoever

Puppy Dog

3rd extra

```html
<?php
  
  // SO UPDATE THE QUERY TO ONLY PULL THAT SHOW'S DOGS
  $query = "SELECT c.* , p.* FROM result c,dogs p WHERE c.dog_id=p.dog_id";
 
  
  $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error
  ("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error
  ($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
  
  if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $placement = $row['placement'];
  $classname = $row['class_name'];
  $dog_name = $row['dog_name'];
  $award = $row['award'];
  
  
  
  
  ?>
  
  
  <table>
   <tr>
   <td><strong><?php echo $classname ?></strong> </td><br>
   </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><strong><?php echo $placement, $award ?></strong>  <?php echo $dog_name ?></td> 
   </tr>
  </table>
  
  
  
  
  
  
     

  <?php  }}} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, don't know why are you using `<table>` inside the while loop, this will print as per your no's of rows.

Here is the basic example, you can store the values in an array than use it with your HTML:

**Example:**

```
<?php
if ($result) {
  $myarr = array();
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $myarr[$row['class_name']][] = $row;  //store values into an array against each class in group
  }
}

foreach ($myarr as $key => $value) {
    echo "Class Name: ". $key."<br/>"; // will print class name
    foreach ($value as $fvalue) {
        echo "Placement: ".$row['placement']."<br/>";; // placement
        echo "Dog Name: ".$row['dog_name']."<br/>"; // dog name
        echo "Award: ".$row['award']."<br/>";; // award
    }
}
?>
```

*Other solution is using incremental variable in while loop as mentioned in other answers.*

Answer (score 1):

Use `counter` to check if it is already displayed:

```
$ctr = 0;
while{
  $classname = $row['class_name'];

  if($ctr == 0){
    echo $classname;
    $ctr++;
  }

  //display the rest
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep track record by index in while loop like :

```
<?php

            // SO UPDATE THE QUERY TO ONLY PULL THAT SHOW'S DOGS
            $query = "SELECT c.* , p.* FROM result c,dogs p WHERE c.dog_id=p.dog_id";


            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or trigger_error
            ("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error
            ($connection), E_USER_ERROR);

            if ($result) {
            $i = 1;
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $placement = $row['placement'];
            $classname = $row['class_name'];
            $dog_name = $row['dog_name'];
            $award = $row['award'];
            ?>  

            <table>
                <tr>
                <td><strong><?php if($i==1) { echo $classname; } ?></strong> </td><br>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><strong><?php echo $placement, $award ?></strong>  <?php echo $dog_name ?></td> 
                </tr>
            </table>








            <?php $i++;  }}} ?>
```

Comment: but still this will print table multiple times.

Comment: yes it will, but i have just provide solution regarding adding class name multiple time

Answer (score 0):

> The Opening and Closing `<Table>` Tags should be outside your Loop *if you expect to have just one Table*. Even the `<tr>` Tags should encompass the `<td>` Tags if you wish to have rows containing 2 Cells like the Code below shows:

```
<?php

    // SO UPDATE THE QUERY TO ONLY PULL THAT SHOW'S DOGS
    $query      = "SELECT c.* , p.* FROM result c,dogs p WHERE c.dog_id=p.dog_id";
    $result     = mysqli_query  ($connection, $query) or trigger_error
                                ("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ".
                                mysqli_error($connection), E_USER_ERROR);
    ?>

    <table>

    <?php
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $placement  = $row['placement'];
            $classname  = $row['class_name'];
            $dog_name   = $row['dog_name'];
            $award      = $row['award'];

    ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <strong><?php echo $classname ?></strong> 
                <!-- DO YOU NEED THIS <BR>TAG HERE? <br> -->
            </td>
            <td>
                <strong><?php echo $placement, $award ?></strong><?php echo $dog_name ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- EXCEPT IF YOU WISH TO HAVE ONE COLUMN, THE ROW BELOW IS UNNECESSARY -->
        <!--
        <tr>
            <td>
              <strong><?php echo $placement, $award ?></strong>  <?php echo $dog_name ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        -->

    <?php 
        }   // CLOSE THE WHILE LOOP;
        }   // CLOSE THE IF STATMENT;
    ?>
</table>
```